# NSArray returns NULL?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a strange issue. I'm trying to set an array (storageData) to equal data that's being sent back from an endpoint (responseObject). I've logged responseObject, and the data is there, but for some reason when I try and set it for storageData, storageData is returning NULL (even though I've declared storageData for use outside of my block). Does anyone know why this might be? See code:

**.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *storageData;
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[DIOSNode nodeIndexWithPage:@"0" fields:@"title" parameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"storage_item", nil] pageSize:@"20" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Nodes retrieved!");

    self.storageData = responseObject;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@",storageData);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure
}];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

       NSDictionary *temp = [storageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSString *title = [temp objectForKey:@"title"];
      [[cell itemName] setText:title];

    //  NSLog(@"%@", storageData);

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why      storageData = [NSArray new]; is there?

Comment: You are setting storageArray in an asynchronous callback. It won't be set when the function returns, but at some point in the future. So be prepared for it being nil, and reload the table view when the data arrives.

Answer (score 3):

`nodeIndexWithPage:...` is likely executing asynchronously.

It returns before the data is fetched and then your table view methods are hardwired to 5 rows and, thus, the table tries to fill with data that isn't loaded yet.

Have your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method return `[storageData count]`.

You are already calling -reloadData in the completion block, so the table will automatically refresh on successful load.

---

Are you also manually declaring instance variables?

If so, then `storageData = ...` and `self.storageData =` won't actually set the same thing (unless you also override -storageData and -setStorageData:).

Make everything reference it via `self.storageData`.

---

Are you sure you are working with just one instance of the class that displays the data?

I.e. Add `NSLog(@"%p", self);` to the beginning of `viewDidLoad`.  Hopefully, it only logs once.   It should only print one hexadecimal number.

NSLog() always prints something.  If it isn't printing anything, then the code isn't being executed.

Comment: Agreed. The implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection` should not be written to return a hardcoded number.

Comment: @rmaddy I changed numberofRowsInSection to return storageData count. I don't get the error anymore, but storageData is still null?

Comment: It is nil after you reload the table in the completion handler?

Comment: Try changing any references to `storageData` to `self.storageData`.

Comment: @rmaddy Tried; stil NULL.

Comment: @rmaddy I've changed all references to storageData, here's the strange thing: now I don't get (null) returned in the console when I log storageData in the table, but I get nothing? Almost like the code isn't even there. O_o

Answer (score 0):

Your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method should return `storageData.count` instead of a hardcoded 5.

Comment: Changed numberofRowsInSection to return storageData.count. I don't get the error anymore, but storageData is still null?